# How many Product Backlog Items came into the Sprint Backlog during this Sprint?

Tags: azure-devops

We are using Azure DevOps for our backlog management.

The question I have is how to know (or measure) how many Product Backlog Items came into the current Sprint Backlog *after* the Sprint started. We are trying to get insight(s) into how much work has changed during a Sprint to have an indication of work stability / influx stability.

Work can come into the current Sprint in the following ways:

1. New Findings are found, these can be changed to a Bug or a Feature after triage;
2. An inspection of the Sprint Backlog during a Daily Scrum prompts re-ordering. This can also mean that PBIs of another (future) Sprint are re-ordered to the current Sprint.

#### What we have tried already:

| Solution | Problems faced |
| --- | --- |
| Create a DevOps Query that filters out all newly created PBIs in the `@CurrentIteration`. This solves point 1. | Only newly created PBIs will surface, PBIs that are older remain unseen. Point 2 remains unsolved. |
| Manually try to copy-paste / use the data of Azure DevOps in Excel. | This solution is not only labor intensive, it is very prone to be outdated during processing in Excel. We have not been successful in having this method work for us. |

Any help is appreciated in finding the answer on how to gain insight(s) into Sprint Backlog work stability / influx stability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, we now use the following Query in Azure DevOps to determine Sprint influx:
[image: DevOps Query]

Pro: It gives us the information that we need.

Con: We need to manually change `Iteration Level 2`, `State Change Date` and `Iteration Path` at the beginning of each Sprint.